# A strange symbol-where can I find it?

Tags: xetex, relation-symbols

Please, in which LaTeX package can I find the symbol between $s$ and $\langle n\rangle$ below ?

[image]

Comment: `\frown`.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are asking for the first one in the example below (`\frown`). The second one is a variant provided by `amssymb` (`\smallfrown`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

 $s \frown \langle n\rangle$

 $s \smallfrown \langle n\rangle$
 
\end{document}
```